# Reading, erasing and rewriting problem in stm32f103cb

Tags: c, stm32

I was read the hex file from stm32f103cb MCU, then I erased it and rewrite the hex file which I was read again into the same MCU but it does not work as before, I use ST-Link utility

the programming process was complete successfully, but not working
every thing was good before erasing, just read , erase and reflash I do not know where is the problem

please help me
Thanks

Comment: To me it means one of the two things: either there WAS some difference in what actually ended up on MCU flash, or you boot from system bootloader the second time, and not from flash. If the flash contents were identical, the behavior also would have been identical, there is simply no other way it can work on a physical level. Look for difference. Program it with working code, make a dump, erase and program (so it doesn't work although it should), and make a dump as well. Compare byte by byte (there are simple tools that show differences between files).